# Meteor pass value from modal click event to parent template

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to make a re-useable confirm modal in Meteor. I have the modal working in the sense it opens and displays the content. The idea is I can use this anywhere and it will return a value if the user clicks confirm then I can run any server side method I choose. The confirm template js is simple and looks like this:

```
Template.confirm.events({
  'click .confirm': function() {
    // I want to let the template that opened the modal know the user has confirmed. How do I pass this information?
  },
  'click .cancel': function() {
    //Close the modal
  }
});
```

I know there are solutions e.g sweet alerts but I am using Zurb Foundation for my UI and want to keep everything within this framework for consistency and control. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you open the modal? That code matters here because that's that's where you'd need to add some code to send along information about the current (calling) template. Depending on how you do that there may be some options. As a fallback you could, of course, always use a global variable (or a session variable).

Comment: @ChristianFritz I'm opening the modal via the url like on this example - https://meteorhacks.com/meteor-ui-pattern-keeping-app-state-in-the-url see the modal close to the bottom of the article

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no standard way to go about this, but I'd suggest passing the modal a `reactiveVar` that you observe outside the modal and trigger your server-side method when the `reactiveVar` changes to the value you want. Some skeleton code might look like:

html

```
{{> confirm triggerVar=myReactiveVar}}
```

modal js

```
Template.confirm.events({
  'click .confirm': function() {
    this.triggerVar.set(true);
  },
  'click .cancel': function() {
    this.triggerVar.set(false);
  }
});
```

in your controller js

```
Template.someTemplate.onCreated(function() {
  this.myReactiveVar = new ReactiveVar();
})

Template.someTemplate.onRendered(function() {
    // observe changes on your fancy reactiveVar
    this.autorun(() => {
        if (this.myReactiveVar.get() === true) {
            // fire whatever server-side action you want
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I appreciate it. I'll give this a go. My only concern here is if I have another modal on the same template that calls the confirm (which I do) will this not react to the ReactiveVar?

Comment: Depends on how you're using it...sharing this reactiveVar with other templates means any template can fire your `onRendered` code above. Depends on how you structure your modal if `myReactiveVar` triggers changes in the other modal.

Comment: Would I be able to narrow the scope if I had a `var instance = Template.instance()` then `this.instance.autorun()` ?

Comment: That's actually precisely what's being done above...`this.autorun` is a template-scoped autorun for data available to the `someTemplate` template only (i.e. `this === Template.instance()`). I'm not clear how you're hoping to narrow the scope...

Comment: What I meant by narrowing the scope is I have a table of users with each row having a remove user button that triggers the confirm modal. I was trying to think of a way for the autorun to not trigger them all. I will play with the code a little more and figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, sure - each template instance just needs to handle its own reactiveVar, then. create `myReactiveVar` in the template `onCreated` event. I edited the answer to reflect that.